# Properly shaping LSTM input/output for text sequence prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to learn how to use an LSTM to predict the next character based on the previous character. I've successfully created a function that batches a long string of text (after one-hot encoding) into shape `(batch_size, seq_len, one_hot_features)`. `one_hot_features` is simply the number of unique characters in the text.

Since my batching function gives me both training sequences and 'ground truth' sequences, I need the output of the LSTM network to be the same shape as the 'ground truth' batches so that I can plug both output and labels into the loss function.

So my questions are:

1. How do I correctly define my network architecture to meet the above requirements.
2. How do I shape my data as it passes through the various layers in the `forward` function?

This is my attempt, and the code will run, but the output of the network is incorrectly shaped for comparison to the 'ground truth' sequence batches:

```
class charNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=0.5):
        super().__init__()

        self.vocab_length = len(vocab)
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.vocab_length, hidden_size, n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc   = nn.Linear(hidden_size, self.vocab_length)
        
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        x, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)     # -> (n_batches, seq_len, hidden_size)
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.hidden_size)  # -> (n_batches * seq_len, hidden_size)
        x = self.fc(x)                       # -> (n_batches * seq_len, vocab_length)
        
        return x, hidden
```

Thank you in advance. I've been struggling with this one for a couple days. I will also happily provide the code for training the network, if it is required. It does not throw any errors except to tell me that the output size and the true label sizes do not match.

Comment: Hi, have you considered adding additional dense or even a linear layer  to bring the output of the lstm to the desired shape ? Then you will also need to tweak the hidden layer of the lstm module accordingly to achieve the target shape.  A combination of this gives you want you want. The inherent optimization method of your module would make sure this additional layer wont affect the training accuracy. Best

Comment: @smile That's an interesting idea, but I'm having a hard time visualizing what you mean. As I'm still learning about LSTMs (and DL in general), I think I would prefer a solution that is simple and easily generalizable to other types of data. For this reason, I'm hoping to find the simplest architecture that does the trick before I start messing with adding new layers.

Comment: @rockNwaves    I got your point. I guess you already have an overall plan for the full architecture. But  you need to also ensure  that the linear algebra of the architecture checks out and is interpretable in terms of the output you want. So for example you might decide to use additional lstm cell(s), or add other  layer or any other operation that helps give the desired out.  You could also observe that in the proposed answer, this is what it is trying to do. Take charge of the architecture and let it work for you . Best

Comment: @smile, Not a plan per-se, just a desire to keep it simple until I understand what's going on. So you are saying that there is a possibility that what I want to do isn't achievable without adding extra layers? That would be an answer in itself...

Comment: @rockNwaves    I think you should also check how the variation in  hidden_size, n_layers  affect the shape of the output or how change in parameter to the lstm cell  [keras lstm](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/)  could change the output size? For example setting the stateful to true will give new behaviour.  If this does not work then additional layers would be of help. Start with minimal additional layer so it is easy to understand. Then move towards the answer provided here. Best

Comment: @smile I've finally figured out that my architecture is perfect as is. I was entirely misunderstanding PyTorch's `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` function. I thought that the network output and the targets/labels had to be the same shape. I was wrong. I'm going to post an answer to reflect my updated understanding. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `input_size`: len(vocab) and you have also stated adequate amount information for `__init__` method.

I'm also a beginner on the lstm.

Answer 1:

According to me, you have already correctly defined your architecture. Maybe you could add the followings:

- `token_size` variable: your output size
- `encoder` and `decoder` structure.
- Method for initializing weights

For instance:

```
class charNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=0.5, token_size):
        super(charNN, self).__init__()
        self.token_size = token_size
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.vocab_length = len(vocab)
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.encoder = nn.Embedding(token_size, vocab_length)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.vocab_length,   
                            hidden_size, 
                            n_layers, 
                            batch_first=True, 
                            dropout=dropout)
        self.fc   = nn.Linear(hidden_size,  
                              self.vocab_length)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size, token_size)
        self.init_weights()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

    def init_weights(self):
        init_range = 0.1
        uniform_(self.encoder.weight, -init_range, init_range)
        zeros_(self.decoder.weight)
        uniform_(self.decoder.weight, -init_range, init_range)
        

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        return (weight.new_zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size,
                                 self.hidden_size),
                weight.new_zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size,
                                 self.hidden_size))
```

Answer 2:

You could use the following structure for the forward function:

```
    def forward(self, input_, hidden_):
        embedded = self.drop(self.encoder(input_))
        output, hidden_ = self.rnn(input_, hidden_)
        output = self.drop(output)
        decoded = self.decoder(output)
        decoded = decoded.view(-1, self.token_size)
        output = log_softmax(decoded, dim=1)
        return output, hidden_
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Hi! the variable `token_size` would be identical to what I have already defined in as `vocab_length`. I'm also not interested in a solution that adds extra complexity, as I am still learning. If you could please answer the question as stated, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!